# Highcharts error #17 when adding series to the chart using angular 4

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement a histogram high chart using angular 4. I am getting error "Highcharts error #17 when adding series to the chart. My code is as follows. The series happens to look fine not sure what the problem could be

Histogram component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'histogram',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 100% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})
export class HistogramChartComponent {

    public options: any;
    chart: any;

    @Input() public series: any;

    constructor() {

        this.options = {

            chart: {
                type: 'histogram'
            },

            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },


            series: []
        };
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }


    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        console.log(this.series);
        this.chart.addSeries(this.series);
    }

}
```

Ending surplus Component that host the histogram component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { EndingSurplus } from '../../../../api/dtos';

export interface ChartSeries {
   data: number[];
 }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ending-surplus-analysis',
  templateUrl: './ending-surplus-analysis.component.html',
})
export class EndingSurplusAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
  isExpanded = false;

  @Input() results: Array<EndingSurplus>  = [];
 chartSeries: Array<ChartSeries> = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addSeries();
  }

  private addSeries() {

    this.results.forEach(element => {
      if (element.data != null)
        this.chartSeries.push({ data: element.data});
    });
  }

}
```

Ending surplus Component html

```
 <div *ngIf="!showTable" class="tab-pane base-strategy-chart fade show active" id="base-strategy-chart--nva" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="chart-tab">
          <div class="tb-container">

            <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
              <div class="tb-cell col-12">
                <histogram [series]="chartSeries">
               </histogram> 
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- sta Chart End -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to recreate [sample Histogram Highchart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/histogram/) with [Angular-Highcharts](https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts) directive in Angular application. Please refer my [stackblitz working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-demo) and below is my sample code

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ChartModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  histogram : Chart;
  data= [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];

  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.histogram= new Chart({
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Histogram'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Data' },
        alignTicks: false
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Histogram' },
        alignTicks: false,
        opposite: true
    }],

    yAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Data' }
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Histogram' },
        opposite: true
    }],

    series: [{
        name: 'Histogram',
        type: 'histogram',
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        baseSeries: 's1',
        zIndex: -1
    }, {
        name: 'Data',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: this.data,
        id: 's1',
        marker: {
            radius: 1.5
        }
    }]
});
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div [chart]="histogram"></div>
```

Comment: The error that i get leads to the following description This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Angular-highcharts doesn't import the any module besides the default by default. This means if you want anything that uses the highcharts-more module, or highcharts-exporting, or really anything, you have to write your own provider for it in the appropriate NgModule. The [readme](https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts#readme) has this example for importing highcharts-more and highcharts-exporting:

```html
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';
import * as exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: () => [ more, exporting ] } // add as factory to your providers
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```