# Getting "Highcharts error #17" when creating histogram (using Highcharts with Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, histogram

I'm trying to create a simple histogram with Highcharts in Angular and I'm receiving the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:245)
    at highcharts.js:270
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.each (highcharts.js:28)
    at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:270)
    at a.Chart.<anonymous> (highcharts.js:245)
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:31)
    at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:244)
    at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:244)
```

I'm going off of the following tutorial provided by Highcharts:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series

After reading about the "type does not exist" error (Highcharts error #17), it appears that Highcharts thinks that I'm missing an extension file called "highcharts-more.js." I've tried many different implementations that include the "highcharts-more.js" file in the solution, however have not had any luck resolving the error.

Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js"></script>

<div [chart]="testHistogram"></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public testHistogram: Chart;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createHistogram();
    }

    createHistogram(): void {
        var options = {
            title: {
                text: 'Test Histogram'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'time (ms)'
                }
            }],
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: '# of items'
                }
            }],
            series: [{
                name: 'Lag Histogram',
                type: 'histogram',
                xAxis: 1,
                yAxis: 1,
                baseSeries: 1
                }, {
                data: [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4]
            }]
        }

        this.testHistogram = new Chart(<any> options);
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  //for the dashboard view
import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am aware that there was a similar question asked about creating a histogram with Highcharts and Angular ([Highcharts error #17 when adding series to the chart using angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310494/highcharts-error-17-when-adding-series-to-the-chart-using-angular-4)). However, I'm using a very simple approach referenced directly from Highcharts' site, and there were a few details missing from the previous question.

I'm thinking that using the *histogram* series type should **not** require the "highcharts-more.js" file and should already be available as long as the "modules/histogram-bellcurve.js" module and "highcharts.js" file is included.

Also, in my .ts, it appears that when the data attribute is included within the *series* option, it throws the error. However, if I remove the data attribute (something that is required to create the histogram), and make it so that the *series* option is no longer an array with 2 elements, I don't receive the error. But I still of course don't have a histogram of data to show. This makes me wonder if Highchart first checks the histogram type of the series option **and** its required corresponding attributes(making sure they are all specified and set to match that of a histogram chart), before deeming a chart to be of type "histogram" or if that is just decided off of what type is specified, disregarding the attributes included/specified.

If anyone out there has a working solution that creates and populates a histogram Highchart successfully using Angular, I would love to know how one would do this.

Comment: Did you try with the [official Highcharts-angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is throwed when you're trying to create a chart with series which doesn't exist. I see that you didn't import the histogram module correctly. You should delete `<script>` tags from your `app.component.html` file, and import the modules inside of `app.module.ts`.

Additionally, in order to make it works, you need to import appropriate module in the mentioned file, just like that:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  //for the dashboard view
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as histogram from 'highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [
      { provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: () => [histogram] }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, I recommend you to use official `highcharts-angular` wrapper, which is very clearly documented and you shouldn't have any problems with building your own chart. Additionally it's better supported than unofficial ones. Here is the link to `npm` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular